# Javascript adding key to factory funciton object

Tags: javascript, object

my apologies if this question has been answered in previous post. I looked but found nothing like it. I am wondering if anyone knows of a way that I can add a key to a resulting object from a factory function. Meaning, outside of the factory function I want to later add a key versus going back to the factory function itself and changing what the out put should be.

```js
/*below you will see where I have tried to add the key from the outside using the function name as the object name similiar to how one would with a standard object but the code below will return undefinded, my guess is because the object has no name, but rather is simply returned.*/

function createCharacter(name, nick, race, origin, attack, defense){
 return {
  name: name,
  nickname: nick,
  race: race,
  origin: origin,
  attack: attack,
  defense: defense,
  describe: function(){
   console.log(`${this.name} is a ${this.race} from ${this.origin}`);
  }
}

createCharacter.weapon = weapon;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the function using `new createCharacter()`:

```js
/*below you will see where I have tried to add the key from the outside using the function name as the object name similiar to how one would with a standard object but the code below will return undefinded, my guess is because the object has no name, but rather is simply returned.*/

function createCharacter(name, nick, race, origin, attack, defense){
 return {
  name: name,
  nickname: nick,
  race: race,
  origin: origin,
  attack: attack,
  defense: defense,
  describe: function(){
   console.log("${this.name} is a ${this.race} from ${this.origin}"+weapon);
  }
    }
}

x = new createCharacter()
x.weapon = "sword";
console.log(x.weapon);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you continue use createCharacter function,get a Character instance like this:

```
function createCharacter(name, nick, race, origin, attack, defense){
    return {
        name: name,
        nickname: nick,
        race: race,
        origin: origin,
        attack: attack,
        defense: defense,
        describe: function(){
            console.log(`${this.name} is a ${this.race} from ${this.origin}`);
        }
   }
}
//just directly invoke factory function,which will return a Character instance
var oneCharacter = createCharacter();
oneCharacter.weapon = "weapon";
```

another way is use constuctor,like this:

```
function Character(name, nick, race, origin, attack, defense){
    this.name = name;
    this.nick = nick;
    this.race = race;
    this.origin = origin;
    this.attack = attack;
    this.defense = defense;
    this.describe = function(){
            console.log(`${this.name} is a ${this.race} from ${this.origin}`);
        }
}
//use keyword "new" get a Character instance 
var oneCharacter = new Character();
oneCharacter.weapon = "weapon";
```